# small caps mathsf font for writing transpose of a matrix

Tags: fonts, small-caps, sans-serif

I would like to produce a small caps sans serif font letter t in math equation mode to typeset transpose. However, `A^{\mathsf{\textsc{t}}}` is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) We kindly suggest you to show a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) on what you have worked so far, so we can help you further with your problem.

Comment: Computer Modern Sans lacks small caps. Besides, `\mathsf` would have no influence over `\textsc`.

Comment: just use `^\mathsf{T}`  unlike `\text..`, `\mathsf` will get smaller in superscript, if you really want it smaller then `^{\scriptscriptsyle\mathsf{T}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computer Modern Sans Serif lacks small caps (and Latin Modern too). Besides, a `\textsc` command inside `\mathsf` would not produce sans serif, because `\mathXX` commands don't accumulate.

If you don't need this in subscripts or superscripts, you can do by

```
\newcommand{\trans}{^{\scriptscriptstyle\mathsf{T}}}
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\trans}{{\scriptscriptstyle\mathsf{T}}}

\begin{document}

Output: $A^{\trans}$

Comparison: $A^{\textsc{t}}$

Subscript: $\mathcal{X}_{A^{\trans}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, the output in subscripts is suboptimal.

A different implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\trans}{}% for safety
\DeclareRobustCommand{\trans}{\mathpalette\aberdysh@trans\relax}
\newcommand{\aberdysh@trans}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \settoheight\unitlength{$\m@th#1{x}$}%
  \begin{picture}(1,1)
  \squarecap
  \Line(0.05,1)(0.95,1)
  \Line(0.5,0)(0.5,1)
  \end{picture}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\trans\scriptstyle\trans\scriptscriptstyle\trans$

Output: $A^{\trans}$

Comparison: $A^{\textsc{t}}$ $A^{\scriptscriptstyle\mathsf{T}}$

Subscript: $\mathcal{X}_{A^{\trans}}$

\end{document}
```

You may want to experiment with `\roundcap` instead of `\squarecap`.

[image]

Comment: isn't there a symbol `\top` that provides this shape?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the following alternative.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\transpose}{%
  {\mathpalette\@transpose{}}%
}
\newcommand*{\@transpose}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: unused
    \small \raisebox{1.37\depth}{$\m@th#1\intercal$}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\tran}{^{\mkern-1.5mu\transpose}}
\newcommand*{\traninv}{^{-\mkern-1.5mu\transpose}}
```